# How to overload android-room Dao methods?

Tags: java, android, android-room

In Android-Room,
I am writing **@Dao** for articleTable entity class.

In this ArticleDao class there are several update methods with different name.

Can I overload android-room methods?

If I overload android-room methods, will they work?

ArticleDao class is in following

```
@Dao
public interface ArticleDao {
    // insert query
    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void insert(ArticleData articleData);

    @Delete
    void delete(ArticleData articleData);

    // delete all query
    @Delete
    void reset(List<ArticleData> articleDataList);

    // update query
    @Query("UPDATE " + Constants.TABLE_NAME_ARTICLE +
            " SET title = :uTitle, content = :uContent  WHERE ID = :uID")
    void updateTitle_Content(int uID, String uTitle, String uContent);

    // update query
    @Query("UPDATE " + Constants.TABLE_NAME_ARTICLE +
            " SET articleID = :uArticleID, title = :uTitle WHERE ID = :uID")
    void updateArticleID_Title_Content(int uID, int uArticleID, String uTitle);

    // update query
    @Query("UPDATE " + Constants.TABLE_NAME_ARTICLE +
            " SET articleID = :uArticleID, title = :uTitle, content = :uContent WHERE ID = :uID")
    void updateAll(int uID, int uArticleID, String uTitle, String uContent);

    // get all data query
    @Query("SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME_ARTICLE)
    List<ArticleData> getAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can overload android-room methods.

android-room method overloading process is same as java method overloading

ArticleDao class is in following with overloaded methods.

```
@Dao
public interface ArticleDao {
    // insert query
    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void insert(ArticleData articleData);

    @Delete
    void delete(ArticleData articleData);

    // delete all query
    @Delete
    void reset(List<ArticleData> articleDataList);

    // update query
    @Query("UPDATE " + Constants.TABLE_NAME_ARTICLE +
            " SET title = :uTitle, content = :uContent  WHERE ID = :uID")
    void update(int uID, String uTitle, String uContent);

    // update query
    @Query("UPDATE " + Constants.TABLE_NAME_ARTICLE +
            " SET articleID = :uArticleID, title = :uTitle WHERE ID = :uID")
    void update(int uID, int uArticleID, String uTitle);

    // update query
    @Query("UPDATE " + Constants.TABLE_NAME_ARTICLE +
            " SET articleID = :uArticleID, title = :uTitle, content = :uContent WHERE ID = :uID")
    void update(int uID, int uArticleID, String uTitle, String uContent);

    // get all data query
    @Query("SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME_ARTICLE)
    List<ArticleData> getAll();
}
```